# Questions using Are, Did and have?

Tags: sentence-construction, verb-forms

> - Are you fell on your head when you were kid?
> - Have you fallen on your head when you were kid?
> - Did you fell on your head when you were kid?

Which one is correct to say.

Comment: The appropriate expression would be: **Did** you **fall** on your head when you were **a** kid? Also note that you only capitalize proper nouns, not common nouns.

Answer (score 1):

Your event took place in the past: “when you were a kid”.

For this reason your first option cannot go as **are** refers to a present event.

The second option doesn’t go too as the event should have ended in the past without any implication to further time sequences.

Your last example is correct if you use the auxiliary do in the past, **did**+bare infinitive **fall**:

Did you fall on your head when you were a kid?

Comment: If i say "Why are you talking like mad? Are you fallen on your head or what?" is it correct to say

Answer (score -1):

Just add an 'a' before the kid and the third one is correct

The second one is wrong because 'have' refers to recent past. For distant past we use 'had'. So the right question would be " Had you fallen on your head when you were a kid?

The first one is wrong , because questions starting with 'Are' refer to the present. 'Fell' is the second form of the verb 'fall' and addresses past.